# Outputting all users and passwords to a file

Tags: powershell, active-directory, export-to-csv

Im trying to create a script where it will take a few users in a CSV file, then change their password and enable it in Active Directory. The trouble is I cant seem to get all the users to output to either a CSV or a text file that looks like this:

```
User1   Password
User2   Password
User3   Password
User4   Password
```

I have tried `Write-Host` and that didn't work, so I was playing with an array, but I still can't seem to get it. Can someone please help me with what I'm doing wrong, so that I can get all the users outputted to a table?

Here is the code that I am using:

```
if (-not (Get-Module ActiveDirectory)){
  Import-Module ActiveDirectory
}

#Construct an out-array to use for data export
$OutArray = @()

# User setup           
$users = Import-Csv "C:\accounts.csv"

foreach ($user in $users) {
  # set up random number generator
  $rand = New-Object System.Random

  #Generate a new password
  $NewPassword = [char]$rand.next(65,90) + [char]$rand.next(65,90) +
                 [char]$rand.next(48,57) + [char]$rand.next(97,122) +
                 [char]$rand.next(48,57) + [char]$rand.next(97,122) +
                 [char]$rand.next(97,122) + [char]$rand.next(35,38)

  #setup username variables
  $username = $user.samAccountName

  #enable ad account
  Enable-ADAccount -Identity $username

  #set-ad password 
  Set-ADAccountPassword $username -NewPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText "$NewPassword" -Force) -PassThru -Reset

  #$outarray += $Username,$NewPassword
  #Write-Host "Password has been set for:" $username  $NewPassword
}

#After the loop, export the array to CSV
$outarray | Export-Csv "c:\login.csv"
```

Comment: `System.Random` should never be used for passwords.  It uses a predictable algorithm.  You should use `System.Security.Cryptography.RNGCryptoServiceProvider` instead, or even something very simple like `[System.Web.Security.Membership]::GeneratePassword(8,0)`.

Comment: @krousemw From security point of view, it would be a brain-dead idea to use a 3rd party non-secure web page to generate your passwords. Dictionary attacks, eavesdropping and man-in-the-middle are way too easy attack vectors.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
$outarray += $Username,$NewPassword
```

Create a new `PsObject` and add it to the array:

```
$OutArray += New-Object PSObject -Property @{UserName=$username; Password=$NewPassword}
```

and export it using:

```
$OutArray | Export-Csv "c:\login.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

With your approach (`$outarray += $Username,$NewPassword`), you just created a string list containing usernames and passwords (without assignments).

You may want to take a look at the [Export-Csv](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849932.aspx) help.

Comment: While this answers the question, please consider adding value by explaining *why* this works and what was wrong in the original approach instead of just giving sample code.

Comment: You are right @vonPryz . I was a little to lazy there.

Comment: Thank you for the help, I have been seemingly banging my head against a a rock for a few days on this. However when it outputted the csv file, it placed the password section in column a and username in column B of the csv file. Why would it output it like that? How can I reverse it?

Comment: Try to select the properties in the order you want, e. g: `$OutArray | select UserName, Password | Export-Csv "c:\login.csv" -NoTypeInformation`

Comment: Hello again, I have a question that's related to the script im working on, but calling the powershell script I'm working on from a batch file. I cant seem to get the context down for why it wont work. Can someone please help me? Here is the code from the batch file:@ECHO OFF
SET PowerShellScriptPath="\\Server\c$\folder\script.ps1"
PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& {Start-Process PowerShell -ArgumentList '-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "%\\Server\c$\folder\script.ps1.ps1%" -Verb RunAs}";