# Batch file Calling a powershell script

Tags: powershell

Im trying to run a batch file on one server to call a powershell script on another server. The way that I need this to run is have the batch file on server 1 execute the powershell script on server 2 then have the powershell script output a file with the details onto server 1 where the batch file resides.

The code that I have for the batch file is as follows:

```
@ECHO OFF
SET PowerShellScriptPath="\\server1\c$\folder\Script.ps1"
PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& {Start-Process  PowerShell -ArgumentList -File "\\server1\c$\folder\Script.ps1" -Verb RunAs}";
```

I need the script to run as admin from the batch file, however it fails and doesnt work and I cant seem to see why. Can anyone see why this isn't working?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you have '%\\server2\c$\folder\script.ps1' as the path? Shouldn't it just be '\\server2\c$\folder\script.ps1'?

Comment: There are better ways of doing this. Remote session on the other server executing commands on the local server comes to mind. Why do you need to run a batch file that executes a powershell script on another server?

Comment: @TheMadTechnician, its for curiousity sake. I have always seen batch files execute something within the same folder. I was curious if it could work doing it on a different server. However I cant seem to make it work, even though it seems accurate in the code i gave at the top. If the access permissions for the shared folders are correct then it should be correct i assume? What are the other ways that I can try this? Is there any powershell commands that would be an alternative, like an invoke?

Comment: Just for clarification, do you want the powershell script to execute (i.e. run all of it's commands) against server 2 or server 1? e.g. If the script deletes a file, are you expecting it to delete the file from server 2 or server 1? Also, when you say it fails, what error message does it give you?

Comment: Hi there, here is my hypothetical scenario. Server 1 is where the batch file resides, and executes the powershell on server2. The powershell script is located here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36291298/outputting-all-users-and-passwords-to-a-file). The idea behind this is so that User A who doesn't have any admin privileges can execute the batch file on server 1 since they don't have access to server 2 ( where PS lives). When i try the bat file on server 2, it works flawlessly, however it always fails when on server 1. When using -executionpolicy i get the error

Comment: @deadlydog where it cannot open anything in the script ( i have a screencapture as well) and when I use `PowerShell invoke-command -filepath "\\server2\script.ps1" -computerName "server2"` it apparently cannot  invoke the script, saying that cannot be loaded because the execution of scripts is disabled on this system. please see "get-help about_signing"

Comment: @squirrel Have you set the execution policy on both servers? I would set it to Unrestricted or RemoteSigned and try again https://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/ee176961.aspx

Comment: This Question is for @deadlydog or anyone really. I cannot set the one server to Unrestricted as it has a few things in place that i cannot change due to security reasons. This then leaves me with 2 more options. I can either setup a user that once is logged in will trigger the batch file to do the same thing. This can be done with either task scheduler or wrap it in a gpo. I have played with both and GPO seems to be the way that I want to go, however I cant seem to get the script to activate in the logon portion of powershell. Does anyone have any thoughts or recommendations?